# How to credit packages used in a commercial flutter project?

Tags: mit, apache-2.0, commercial, bsd

I have used many libraries from the pub dev site in my flutter project and i notices many of them use the bsd, mit or apache 2.0 licence. I want to release this app in the future and have read that you should make sure the library licences are available in the source code. Is this correct?

If I just include them in my pubspec.yaml does this already do this?

If I need to include a reference to all the libraries i use in my project and there licences is there a way to auto generate such a thing in flutter?

I have been reading online and there seems to be a few methods in android to do this e.g.
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/keeping-your-licenses-in-check-411e34a0bcb4

The produces the following output.
[image]

Could anybody help me with this?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's been a few years but maybe it can help.

You can use the official Flutter showLicensePage feature (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showLicensePage.html) which shows the licenses of the packages you are using in the project.